# '<name>' expected near minimum value in lua for loop

Tags: for-loop, lua

```
function calculateGainOverHrs(dronenum, hrs)
    local yypx = 0
    for hrs=hrs,0,-1
    do
        yypx = yypx + calculateGainHour(dronenum)
    end
    return yypx
end
```

I'm trying to create an program that calculates how much money i am gaining from a mining facility (( in a game, of course. )). I wrote a function - the one above, to calculate the gain over a certain number of hours. However, upon running it, I get this error -

```
\LUAPrograms\miningalgoluaport.lua:29: '<name>' expected near '0'
```

The specificness of this question means I couldn't search for it. I'm sure there is a fix, but I just want the hrs argument to feed into the function. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT : The script is as following -

```
    -- Ores --
Cop = 5
Iro = 10
Sil = 150
Gol = 250
Pla = 400
Dia = 1000
Aeg = 1300
Cer = 1700
Rub = 2300
Ura = 1300
Plu = 2100
Sol = 4000
-- Ores --

drones = nil
totalpx = 0

math.randomseed(os.time * 42420451 * 425714 * 0.23)
math.randomseed(math.random(1,29214757862396238564328976))

function calculateGainOverDays(dronenum, days)
    yyypxyyy = calculateGainOverHrs(dronenum, 24) * days
    return yyypxyyy
end

function calculateGainOverHrs(dronenum, hrs)
    local yypx = 0
    for hrs,0,-1
  do
        yypx = yypx + calculateGainHour(dronenum)
    end
    return yypx
end

function calculateGainHour(dronenum)
    local ypx = 0
    orenum = math.random(1,30)
    for orenum,0,-1
    do
        ore = randint(1, 100)
        if (ore >= 1 and ore <= 5)
            px += Cop * dronenum
        end
        else if (ore >= 6 and ore <= 30)
            px += Iro * dronenum
        end
        else if (ore >= 31 and ore <= 52)
            px += Sil * dronenum
        end
        else if (ore >= 53 and ore <= 62)
            px += Gol * dronenum
        end
        else if (ore >= 63 and ore <= 70)
            px += Pla * dronenum
        end
        else if (ore >= 71 and ore <= 77)
            px += Dia * dronenum
        end
        else if (ore >= 78 and ore <= 87)
            px += Aeg * dronenum
        end
        else if (ore >= 88 and ore <= 90)
            px += Cer * dronenum
        end
        else if (ore == 91)
            px += Rub * dronenum
        end
        else if (ore >= 92 and ore <= 97)
            px += Plu * dronenum
        end
        else if (ore >= 98 and ore <= 100)
            px += Sol * dronenum
        end
    end
    return px
end

function menuDisplay()
    print
    (
    "1 - Calculate Ore Gain\n"..
    "2 - Change Drone Number\n"..
    "Total Pixels this Session: " .. tostring(totalpx)
    end
    )
    if (io.read = 1)
        print
        (
        "1 - Over Days \n"..
        "2 - Over Hours \n"..
        "3 - Over an Hour"
        )
        if (io.read() = 1)
            io.write("How many days?")
            local tempI = nil
            local tempII = io.read
            tempI = calculateGainOverDays(drones,tempII)
            print("The facility generated " .. tempI .. "px over" .. tempII .. "days.")
            totalpx = totalpx + tempI
            menuDisplay()
        end
        else if (io.read() = 2)
            io.write("How many hours?")
            local tempI = nil
            local tempII = io.read
            tempI = calculateGainOverHrs(drones,tempII)
            print("The facility generated " .. tempI .. "px over" .. tempII .. "hours.")
            totalpx = totalpx + tempI
            menuDisplay()
        end
        else if (io.read() = 3)
            local tempI = calculateGainHour(drones)
            print("In one hour, the facility generated " .. temp1 .. "px."
            totalpx = totalpx + tempI
            menuDisplay()
        end
    else if (io.read = 2)
        io.write("New Dronenum:")
        drones = io.read
        menuDisplay()
    end
end





--!CORE!--
--!CORE!--
--!CORE!--
--!CORE!--
--!CORE!--
print("Vernet Industries Ore Calculator - Created by Maurice Vernet")

print("Initializing...")

io.write("Enter Number of Drones:")

drones = io.read()

menuDisplay()
```

Comment: In agreement with @PaulKulchenko that code works for me in both lua 5.1 and 5.2. Are you sure that's the code involved?

Comment: Compare the snippet `calculateGainOverHrs` versus the full `calculateGainOverHrs` function and you'll see the change you made in the snippet to fix the problem.

Comment: An IDE (e.g, [Koneki](http://www.eclipse.org/koneki/ldt/)) might help discover errors as you type. Then you can ask one specific question when you get stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many syntax errors in the full script. Here are some of them:

1. You missed `then` in the `if` statements. Also note that `elseif` is a keyword in Lua, it's preferred over `else if` because you don't need the extra `end`. For instance:

   ```
   if (ore >= 1 and ore <= 5)
       --do something
   end       
   else if (ore >= 6 and ore <= 30)
       --do something else
   end
   ```

   should be

   ```
   if ore >= 1 and ore <= 5 then
       --do something
   elseif ore >= 6 and ore <= 30 then
       --do something else
   end
   ```
2. There is no compound assignment in Lua,

   ```
   px += Iro * dronenum
   ```

   should be

   ```
   px = px + Iro * dronenum
   ```
3. `io.read` is the function itself while `io.read()` is the return value of the function, you are using it incorrectly in several places.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I tried to copy and paste Lua code from an iBook into my text editor (Sublime Text 3).  Turns out that there are special characters added which may or may not be visible.

I noticed the syntax in my editor did not look correct so I retyped a function.  Not only did it work but the syntax was different from the pasted code.